# Problem printing predict output in an C++ code generated using MATLAB Coder

Tags: c++, matlab, neural-network, matlab-coder

I translated my MATLAB code to C++ using MATLAB Coder and I changed the main.cpp to create a executable. Everything seems ok until here, but when I print my predict output, my classname has an extra character. How can I solve this situation? Classes are virginica and versicolor. When I run my program in command line, output is something like this: versicolorÌ

What am I doing wrong?

```
MATLAB Entry-Function
function output_lab = testMod(input_data)

    Mod = loadCompactModel('model');
    output_lab = predict(Mod, input_data);

end
```

```
GENERATED CODE
int main(int argc, const char * const argv[])
{

  double input_data[4];
  cell_wrap_0 output_lab[1];

  for (int contador = 0; contador < 4; contador++)
  {
      input_data[contador] = atof(argv[contador + 1]);
      printf("%f ", input_data[contador]);
  }

  printf("\n");

  testMod_initialize();

  testMod( input_data, output_lab);

  cout << output_lab[0].f1.data;

  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably you are trying to display an array of characters which is not terminated by 0. So one or more following junk characters are printed until 0 is found.

Comment: @jszpilewski I figured out what was the problem and It was something related to what you said. cell_wrap_0 is a struct with a size field and I have to use it properly to print my variable.

Comment: @FFFF Great that you figured it out! Consider posting your fixed code as an answer so future readers can see what you did to resolve the issue.